# Truth table for the zebra puzzle

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-logic, truthtable, zebra-puzzle

I'm reading "Computer Science distilled" book and I've faced a trouble. Author suggests to solve Einstein's "Zebra puzzle" through truth table, but I can't figure out how. I can't find starting conditions and variables. Do you have any ideas of the smallest table possible? I suppose I can create only a 6^6 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of the book the OP mentioned. I didn't mean for the reader to use *only* a big truth table to solve the Zebra Puzzle, but rather, so use it as a tool to detect situations that can never happen, and to better direct the exploration process.

Using a big truth table with variables representing a house/attribute state, you can spot a variable that, if true, would imply a lot of relevant states. It's best to test these variables for finding logical contradictions than simply bruteforcing all the variables.

I wrote a detailed blog post explaining how to solve the Zebra puzzle using only simple inferences and boolean algebra, here: https://code.energy/solving-zebra-puzzle/

Answer (score 1):

A typical riddle can be viewed as a k×n matrix and then encoded with k×n<sup>2</sup> boolean variables like [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs372/2008sp/372-sp08-hwk4.pdf). Consider a variable P<sub>ijm</sub> to be true if — and only if — the (i,j)-entry in the matrix has value m.

Obviously, you need a SAT solver to solve a riddle encoded in this way. I suppose the author suggests you to use truth tables just ironically, or for pedagogical reasons, or he/she asks you to implement techniques used in SAT solvers.

In order to reduce the number of “terms” involved one have to model this puzzle in a (decidable) fragment of first-order logic, e.g. Horn clauses (Prolog) or description logic (OWL reasoners).

Another example of such a “propositional explosion” of the number of terms is the propositional pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 0):

The [MiniZinc](http://www.minizinc.org/) script below shows how to encode the zebra puzzle in terms of `25` decision variables. Each of them has a value 1..5. In terms of Boolean variables, `25*3 = 75` bits would be needed.

A direct Boolean encoding as suggested by @Stanislav Kralin would require `5*5*5 = 125` Boolean decision variables.

A somewhat more elegant version can be found [here](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/blob/master/tests/examples/zebra.mzn). It exhibits the same number of decision variables.

```
%  Zebra Puzzle in MiniZinc
%  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle

%  for all_different()
include "globals.mzn";

%  Number of houses (cf. constraint 1.)
int: n = 5;
set of int: House = 1..5;

%  Nationalities
var House: English;
var House: Spaniard;
var House: Ukranian;
var House: Norwegian;
var House: Japanese;

%  Beverages
var House: Coffee;
var House: Tea;
var House: Milk;
var House: Orange_Juice;
var House: Water;

%  Pets
var House: Dog;
var House: Horse;
var House: Snail;
var House: Fox;
var House: Zebra;

%  House colors
var House: Red;
var House: Yellow;
var House: Ivory;
var House: Blue;
var House: Green;

%  Cigarette brands
var House: Old_Gold;
var House: Kools;
var House: Chesterfield;
var House: Lucky_Strike;
var House: Parliaments;

%  Explicit constraints
% 1. There are five houses.

% 2. The Englishman lives in the red house.
constraint English = Red;

% 3. The Spaniard owns the dog.
constraint Spaniard = Dog;

% 4. Coffee is drunk in the green house.
constraint Coffee = Green;

% 5. The Ukranian drinks tea.
constraint Ukranian = Tea;

% 6. The green house is immediately to the right of the ivory house.
constraint Green = (Ivory + 1);

% 7. The Old Gold smoker owns snails.
constraint Old_Gold = Snail;

% 8. Kools are smoked in the yellow house.
constraint Kools = Yellow;

% 9. Milk is drunk in the middle house.
constraint Milk = (n + 1)/2;

% 10. The Norwegian lives in the first house.
constraint Norwegian = 1;

% 11. The man who smokes Chesterfields lives in the house next to the man with the fox.
constraint abs(Chesterfield - Fox) = 1;

% 12. Kools are smoked in the house next to the house where the horse is kept.
constraint abs(Kools - Horse) = 1;

% 13. The Lucky Strike smoker drinks orange juice.
constraint Lucky_Strike = Orange_Juice;

% 14. The Japanese smokes Parliaments.
constraint Japanese = Parliaments;

% 15. The Norwegian lives next to the blue house.
constraint abs(Norwegian - Blue) = 1;

%  Implicit constraints
%  each of the five houses is painted a different color
constraint all_different([Red, Blue, Yellow, Green, Ivory]);

%  inhabitants are of different national extractions
constraint all_different([English, Spaniard, Ukranian, Norwegian, Japanese]);

%  inhabitants own different pets
constraint all_different([Dog, Horse, Snail, Fox, Zebra]);

%  inhabitants drink different beverages 
constraint all_different([Coffee, Tea, Milk, Orange_Juice, Water]);

%  inhabitants smoke different brands of American cigarets [sic]
constraint all_different([Old_Gold, Kools, Chesterfield, Lucky_Strike, Parliaments]);

solve satisfy;

function string: take(int: h, array[1..n-1] of House: x, array[House] of string: s) =
  if x[1] = h then s[1] 
  elseif x[2] = h then s[2] 
  elseif x[3] = h then s[3] 
  elseif x[4] = h then s[4] 
  else s[5] endif;

output ["\nColor       "] ++
       [ take(h, [fix(Red), fix(Blue), fix(Green), fix(Ivory)], 
                 ["red          ", "blue         ", "green        ", "ivory        ", "yellow       "])| h in House] ++
       ["\nNationality "] ++
       [ take(h, [fix(English), fix(Spaniard), fix(Ukranian), fix(Norwegian)],
                 ["English      ", "Spaniard     ", "Ukranian     ", "Norwegian    ", "Japanese     "])| h in House] ++
       ["\nPet         "] ++
       [ take(h, [fix(Dog), fix(Horse), fix(Snail), fix(Fox)],
                 ["Dog          ", "Horse        ", "Snail        ", "Fox          ", "Zebra        "])| h in House] ++
       ["\nBeverage    "] ++
       [ take(h, [fix(Coffee), fix(Tea), fix(Milk), fix(Orange_Juice)],
                 ["Coffee       ", "Tea          ", "Milk         ", "Orange Juice ", "Water        "])| h in House] ++
       ["\nCigarette   "] ++
       [ take(h, [fix(Old_Gold), fix(Kools), fix(Chesterfield), fix(Lucky_Strike)],
                 ["Old Gold     ", "Kools        ", "Chesterfield ", "Lucky Strike ", "Parliaments  "])| h in House];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code I wrote for the [puzzle-solvers](https://github.com/madphysicist/puzzle-solvers) package. It was made to solve a similar question right here on SO. Since it's a very small package, you can probably see how the code is written quite easily.

The code is the [`Solver`](https://puzzle-solvers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elimination.html#puzzle_solvers.elimination.Solver) class, which maintains a matrix of values and provides the methods you need to set up relationships that automatically prune the underlying graph of contradictory edges.

You can follow along with a detailed description of the logic from the [docs](https://puzzle-solvers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elimination.html#logic). This really explains how the matrix representation of the graph is used to record the relationships in the rules. The gist of it is that each rule either sets up a direct link between two categories, which prunes all the contradictory edges, or eliminates an edge, which has implications as well.